# JQuery table search cut table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Have tried using `jQuery` in order to create search input for my `HTML` table. Actually it is somehow working. However I have noticed unwanted behavior and it is when I search for some word which is not in the `table header` it cut the header so only content that is left is the row which contains searched word which was put in the input field.

Here is my script:

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Mithrand1r/rn74Z/2/)

Could anyone give me a hint how can I improve this code to show result of the search within table headers?

PS. Edited link. Previous one did not include jquery and was not working. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select matching `tr` only from `tbody`. See the updated Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rn74Z/3/

Answer (score 0):

This way it'll filter only whole rows that contains td tags and not headers:

```
var rows = $('#xxx tr');
...
rows.show().has("td").filter(....)
```